# Elementary set theory problem - lack of working memory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Here's an example to illustrate the problem:

I have this problem from a book about set theory:

$\wp(\cup_{i \in I}A_i)\nsubseteq \cup_{i \in I} \wp(A_i)$

I'm supposed to translate it to pure logical symbols, but after many attempts I couldn't, so I looked at the answers and this is the answer:

$\exists x(\forall y(y \in x \rightarrow \exists i \in I(y \in A_i)) \wedge \forall i \in I \exists y(y \in x \wedge y \notin A_i))$

By this I think they mean:

"There exists such a set $x$ that for every number $y$ in this set, there is a set $i$ from the family of sets $I$ that this number is also in, and for every set $i$ from the family $I$, there is a number $y$ such that $y$ is inside set $x$ and $y$ is not inside set $A_i$"

I'm probably way off and even if I can follow the meaning of the symbols I can't get the big picture. I was going trough the book easily and then as soon as power-sets and families of sets came into play, I feel like I hit a wall. I just can't do it, is it a matter of having high working memory and fitting the big picture in your head?

Comment: Have you tried a more simple version such as $\wp(A \cup B)\nsubseteq \wp(A) \cup \wp(B)$? Also the answer is not completely written using pure logical symbols...

Comment: @dani_s ok almost got it, just one last clarification... 

$\cup_{i \in I} \wp(A_i)$

means the union of all power sets of all sets in the family $I$, right?

Comment: of all sets in the family indexed by $I$ :)